# How to compare the modified date of two files in python?

Tags: python

I am creating a python script that will access each line from a Text file(say File.txt) one by one then search for corresponding '.py' and '.txt' file in the system directory. For example if "COPY"(the first line) is accessed from "File.txt" then search will be done for "COPY.py" and "COPY.txt". If both the files are found then their modification date will be compared. Code have no syntax error But I am getting the wrong output.

**My Python code is:**

```
for line in fileinput.input(r'D:\Python_Programs\File.txt'):
    line = line[0:-1]
    sc = ''.join((line,'.py'))
    lo = ''.join((line,'.txt'))
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'D:\txt and py'):
        if sc in files:
            pytime = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root, sc)))
            print(sc, '   :', pytime)
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
                if txt in files:
                    txttime = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root, txt)))
                    print(txt, '  :', txttime)
                    if (txttime > pytime):
                        print('PASS', '\n')
                    else:
                        print('FAIL', '\n')
```

**Output:**

```
COPY.py     : Mon Aug 27 10:50:06 2012
COPY.txt    : Mon Feb 04 11:05:31 2013
PASS        #Expected = PASS

COPY2.py    : Fri Feb 08 16:34:43 2013
COPY2.txt   : Sat Sep 22 14:19:32 2012
PASS        #Expected = FAIL

COPY3.py    : Fri Feb 08 16:34:53 2013
COPY3.txt   : Mon Sep 24 00:50:07 2012
PASS        #Expected = FAIL
```

I am not getting why "COPY2" and "COPY3" are giving "PASS". May be I am doing it in a wrong way.
As well as on changing the comparison as **"if (txttime < pytime)"** in the code.
All results are showing as "FAIL" in output.

Comment: Instead of using raw strings for windows paths, instead just use forward slashes - it will work fine (and will also work on other platforms).

Comment: you can use [`os.stat(filename).st_mtime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html#stat.ST_MTIME) here, it returns the last modification time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`time.ctime` returns a string and `'Fri Feb 08 16:34:53 2013' < 'Mon Sep 24 00:50:07 2012'`

Answer (score 47):

[`time.ctime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.ctime) formats a time as a string, so you're comparing the strings `"Fri Feb 08 16:34:43 2013"` and `"Sat Sep 22 14:19:32 2012"` textually. Just don't do that and compare the `float`s that `getmtime()` gives you directly:

```
pytime = os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root, sc))
# ...
txttime = os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root, txt))
# ...
if (txttime > pytime):
    # ...
```

Comment: Thank you It works fine now. My problem is solved but How my code in giving "Pass" all the time by comparing the strings. Is it a ASCII value comparison?

Comment: @AshA Yes. It essentially compares whether the string `Fri…` would come in the dictionary before the string `Sat…`, which it would because `F` comes before `S`.

Comment: @millimoose Yes, yet it's practical to see quickly that there's an accepted answer. (Thanks for it, by the way.)

Comment: @zezollo - What I mean is if it wasn't accepted in three years, it's not going to, not by a user that's for all intents and purposes gone. And while I appreciate the sentiment, it's a little spammy.