# Compare dates of two files Python

Tags: python, bash

I am comparing the dates of two files in Python (If the last modification time from today to yesterdey is 24 hours) from a remote machine:

I am trying by this way:

```
commandcomp = 'echo `stat -c%Y /var/tmp/check_ipsleft/today.txt /var/tmp/check_ipsleft/yesterday.txt` | bc'
outputcomp = check_output(commandcomp, shell=True)
```

In the local machine this command works:

```
`echo `stat -c%Y /var/tmp/check_ipsleft/today.txt /var/tmp/check_ipsleft/yesterday.txt` | bc` 


/bin/sh: -c: línea 0: EOF inesperado mientras se buscaba un ``' coincidente
/bin/sh: -c: línea 1: error sintáctico: no se esperaba el final del fichero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "checkipleft.py", line 46, in <module>
    outputcomp = check_output(commandcomp, shell=True)
  File "/opt/python-dsmc/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'echo "stat -c%Y `/var/tmp/check_ipsleft/today.txt" - "stat /var/tmp/check_ipsleft/yesterday.txt" | bc' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Comment: Why are you calling the shell from Python? It has everything you need on board.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare the modified date of two files in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779775/how-to-compare-the-modified-date-of-two-files-in-python)

Comment: @Klaus D. Do I have a way to do this just by using python?

Comment: @MauriceMeyerI I guess that it does not answer my question because i need to check if the differene is greater than 24 hours

Comment: Just ran `os.stat('.profile').st_ctime - os.stat('.gitconfig').st_ctime` here, result was `-1486294.156592369`.

Comment: @KlausD. question says mtime, not ctime. (Note the `%Y`.)

Comment: @alani Well, it's an example. Do you think you could abstract the right command from comment?

Comment: Well, same as you put but with `st_mtime` instead of `st_ctime`.

Comment: @KlausD. could you please put your comment as an answer of this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to call shell commands in order to retrieve the modification time of a file:

```
os.stat(filename)
```

provides a names tuple with all kind of metadata about the file:

```
os.stat_result(st_mode=33204, st_ino=33035339, st_dev=64769, st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_size=589825, st_atime=1597670243, st_mtime=1597662878, st_ctime=1597670176)
```

As [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result) the `st_mtime` field contains the time of most recent content modification as a UNIX timestamp.

You can do any kind of calculation with this, for example:

```
os.stat('1.txt').st_mtime - os.stat('2.txt').st_mtime
```